# Convert String with ascii value to normal string

Tags: java, string, integer, ascii, converters

Here is my code :

```
int availableBytes = inputStream.available();
if (availableBytes > 0) {
    inputStream.read(readBuffer, 0, availableBytes);
    System.out.println(new String(readBuffer, 0, availableBytes));
Reponse = new String(readBuffer, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(Reponse);
```

My question :

So I get in my "Reponse" variable, of type String, ascii value well I think because when I do the sysout of "Reponse" it shows me a 3 "squares with a question mark in".

So is it possible to convert this String value with ascii value in integer ?

Comment: Hint: to "print" an array, use `Arrays.toString()`

Comment: I can't use Arrays.toString() to an String :( ?

Comment: Is this really an ASCII string which you get as a return? Somehow I doubt it. Do you have the packet format? If yes, can you update your question with it?

Comment: -1: Please EDIT your code and REMOVE all the unnecessary mess from there so you leave here only the code relevant for your question. This looks rather like a very lazy attitude and one is not very willing to spend his/her time with answering.

Comment: Here is what I got : http://s17.postimg.org/hwwkp1d4r/Raw.png

Comment: @Honza Zidek: I Edited my code, I just put all the code to let you know what I was trying to do in which context.

Comment: @D3fman: so see my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

Java String is not a sequence of bytes - signed 8-bit, but of chars - unsigned 16-bit. Also read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) for your constructor:

> Constructs a new String by decoding the specified subarray of bytes
>   using the platform's default charset. The length of the new String is
>   a function of the charset, and hence may not be equal to the length of
>   the subarray.

It does not work as you probably expect - it does not convert each byte into a character!